# Get path to child property instance using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, linq-expressions

I'm not looking for a magic lambda expression, I am looking for a viable way to solve my problem in the simplest manner possible.

I have some legacy code I cannot change to better fit my requirements, so I'm looking for a workaround. What I have:

```
public class Settings
{
    public class SubSettings 
    {
         [SampleAttribute]
         public string Prop1 { get; set; }

         public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    } 

    public class SubSettingsExtended1:SubSettings
    {            
    } 

    public class SubSettingsExtended2:SubSettings
    {            
    } 

    public List<SubSettings> Defaults { get; set; }
    public List<SubSettings> Instances {get; set; }
}
```

the instance I'll be working with is

```
var mSettings = new Settings();
mSettings.Defaults.Add((new SubSettingsExtended1()).PopulateFromFile());
var testInstance = (new SubSettingsExtended2()).PopulateFromFile();
mSettings.Defaults.Add(testInstance);
```

The principle:

An instance of *SubSettingsExtended1* is deserialized from some default values (defaults cannot be in code, as they vary for clients) and added to the *Defaults* list. The same is done for an instance of *SubSettingsExtended2* .

When the application need an instance of *SubSettingsExtended1*, it finds the only one in the *Defaults*, makes a deep copy, and adds it to *Instances* .

There is a procedure that maps out every property existing in an object that has the *[SampleAttribute]*, and uses it to store and match some external related data. Let's call the function that does that *GeneratePaths*.

```
var paths = GeneratePaths(new SubSettingsExtended1());
```

would produce a list of strings containing:

```
[
    "root.Prop1",
]
```

while

```
var paths = GeneratePaths(mSettings);
```

would produce a list of strings containing:

```
[
    "root.Defaults.[0].Prop1",
    "root.Defaults.[1].Prop1"
]
```

When a default instance is deep copied into instances, I need to change the path from the default one (*"root.Prop1"*) into a relative one (*"root.Instances.[i].Prop1"*, where i is the appropriate index).

Problem is, there are quite a few places this procedure takes place, as there are several defaults collections and several instances collections, with different paths.

What I need is something like

```
GenerateRelativePath(mSettings=>mSettings.Instances[i]);
GenerateRelativePath(mSettings=>mSettings.Instances.At(i));
GenerateRelativePath(mSettings=>mSettings.Instances.OfType<SubSettingsExtended2>().FirstOrDefault());
```

that would all return the string value

```
"Instances.[i]"
```

As an upgrade, it could find the instance (provided there was guaranteed only one reference in the tree) just by giving something like

```
GenerateRelativePath(mSettings => testInstance);
```

and generate the path from that.

I suspect something like this could be done using Expressions and reflection, but am too lost in expressions to figure it out myself.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Singletons and Reflection. What could possibly go wrong? I must say the code doesn't present clearly what you're trying to do (at least I didn't get it). Your first snippet has a `SettingsTypeInstance`, a `SettingsTypeClass`, mentions `root.Property` and `rootWindow.Settings.Properts` and it's unclear what "Produces" means (Returns? Injects somewhere through reflection?). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I don't actually see where LINQ comes into play here. Of course, there's a lot to it, but in short its just a concise way to loop/filter/sort/group, which doesn't appear to be related to what you want.

Comment: After reading the last part of the question, it seems like you want to get a string representation of an `Expression`?

Comment: I'd say a nasty word here but it would be inappropriate. I'm sorry, I'm a bit burned out, so I got most of my friggin terms mixed up and wrote up a non-representive example. Let me edit the question to make more sense. Lambda, not LINQ. Can't believe what I did here.

Comment: @Groo I do, but in a specific format, the one specified. Give me a few minutes. it should make more sense, without the ballast.

Comment: @JasonX Did you find a solution?

Comment: @IanYates Sadly, no. Decided to go a whole other route as a consequence.